# remove empty spaces from array using angular

Tags: angularjs

im taking first steps in angular, and i need to return array excluding empty spaces in it. i was able to create function to return the array i want, spliced, but couldn't find a way to make sure each cell in the array contains a value.
this is my function:

```
$scope.letters = function(arr) {
    var lettersarray = arr.split('');
    return lettersarray;
};
```

is there a way to do it in angular?

- i know a way in jquery but understood its not recommended to mix both so im looking for an "angularish" way to do it..thx

Answer (score 1):

There's no real "Angular" way to do it, why not just use native JS and `.map`

```
function trimArraySpaces(arr) {
    return arr.map(function(item) {
        return item.trim();
    });
}

var testArr = ["John    ", "Sally    "],
    trimmedArr = trimArraySpaces(testArr); //["John", "Sally"]
```